Is it possible to calculate image storage size based on the number of Fourier Coefficients?
I'm working on image compression using 2D DFT (Discrete Fourier Transform) and am currently trying to calculate the size of the image after I apply the compression (basically leaving only a percentage of the highest magnitude coefficients). I know that image size is usually found through multiplying the resolution and color depth, however DFT compression doesn't affect either resolution or depth, however the size still gets reduced because we have, say, only 10% of coefficients left. So my question is whether it's possible to calculate the image size (in bytes) through the number of Fourier coefficients? Like, a 100x100 pixel image will have 100x100 coefficients, and I though if maybe you could multiply the number of fourier coefficients by some number to get the actual size.
If needed, my main source is this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KGiV_2i713I

my comment from the SO post: you can estimate it. the closer you want to come to the actual result of compression, the more of the compression algorithm you have to execute. the next step would be to quantize the coefficients. further steps: put them into some prescribed order, take however many, code them. you know, typical DCT/DFT based compression on tiles of whatever size you choose.

Just like your spatial pixels have a bitdepth, so do your DFT coefficients.
The size saving comes from

using fewer bits for coefficients that contribute less visually relevant information
applying entropy coding to the remaining bitstream.

So, 1. is your design choice, and by saying "I use this bitdepth for these coefficients, and that bitdepth for those coefficients", you define the number of bits the overal image needs.
Entropy coding (e.g. runlength, Lempel-Ziv(-Welch) methods like DEFLATE/Z77, or Huffman methods, or Markov chain models, or assymetric number system compressors, and typically, combinations thereof) is typically applied to the coefficient stream after elegant reordering, putting similar coefficient next to each other. The question how many bits come out of that fully depends on your image content. You'd need a method to accurately estimate the redundancy the entropy coder can eliminate; but almost always, the fastest estimate (and 100% accurate) is to actually run that entropy coder.
So,

your design choice of coefficient quantization
depends on the output of the previous stage and typically needs to be figured out by actually compressing it.


"So, 1. is your design choice, and by saying "I use this bitdepth for these coefficients, and that bitdepth for those coefficients", you define the number of bits the overal image needs." Would it be correct to say the following: If I have a 10x10 pixel grayscale image, its size will be 800 bits, therefore 1 DFT coefficient takes up 8 bits. And then I can use bitdepth zero for all the low contribution coefficients, and leave 8 bit depth for the significant ones, hence reducing image size? And one more request, would it be possible to send any reference links to learn more about DFT bitdepth?

"I have a 10x10 pixel grayscale image, its size will be 800 bits," Ok, you're assuming you use a bitdepth of 8 bit per pixel, "therefore 1 DFT coefficient takes up 8 bits." No, that is not an inference that can be made. Again, that's the design choice you are making there.

Recommendation: Do a 4-point one-dimensional DFT on 8 bit integers $(a, b, c, d)$, by hand, on paper. (I promise, it's easy! Really!) You will notice that you inherently need to widen your integers to retain the information. Also, even for real-valued input you get complex-valued DFTs, so, that 8bit really can't be right.

Ok, thanks for the suggestion!
